# How to obtain the different record while comparing two different extracts?

Tags: oracle, plsql

For the same table, I am getting different counts for both the below queries, just because of addition of to_char() function in the 2nd query. How can I identify due to which record am I getting the difference ?

```
select count(1) from (select  a1,a2,a4,a5, sum(a6), sum(a7),vap_code,vat_code from table1
              WHERE batchid = l_batchid AND a2 IS NOT NULL 
              GROUP BY a1,a2,a4,a5,vap_code,vat_code HAVING sum(nvl(a6,0)+nvl(a7,0)) <> 0)
```

The count from the above query is 8997.

```
select count(1) from (select  a1,a2,to_char(a4,'RRRRMMDD'),to_char(a5,'RRRRMMDD'), sum(a6), sum(a7),vap_code,vat_code from table1
              WHERE batchid = l_batchid AND a2 IS NOT NULL 
              GROUP BY a1,a2,to_char(a4,'RRRRMMDD'),to_char(a5,'RRRRMMDD'),vap_code,vat_code HAVING sum(nvl(a6,0)+nvl(a7,0)) <> 0)
```

And for the above query the count is 8996. How shall I obtain the record that is creating the difference here ?:

Comment: Show the table definition

Comment: a1 - varchar2(100) , a2 - varchar,a4- date , a5 - date , a6 - number, a7 - number and vap_code and vat_code are varchar

Comment: What count do you get if you change the format mask used throughout the second query to `RRRRMMDDHH24MISS`, and if you change it to `SYYYYMMDD`?

Comment: @AlexPoole I will check and tell just  couple of minutes

Comment: @AlexPoole, it is giving the same 8996 in both the circumstances

Comment: Just to be clear - you are still consistently getting 8997 from the first query - ruling out the data just having changed in between the queries being run?

Comment: @AlexPoole That's right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too big for a comment, but does this return any data:

```
select  a1,a2,a4,a5, sum(a6), sum(a7),vap_code,vat_code
from table1
where batchid = l_batchid and a2 is not null 
group by a1,a2,a4,a5,vap_code,vat_code
having sum(nvl(a6,0)+nvl(a7,0)) <> 0
minus
select a1, a2, to_date(a4, 'RRRRMMDD') a4, to_date(a5, 'RRRRMMDD') a5, suma6, suma7, vap_code, vat_code
from (
  select  a1,a2,to_char(a4,'RRRRMMDD') a4,to_char(a5,'RRRRMMDD') a5, sum(a6) suma6, sum(a7) suma7,vap_code,vat_code
  from table1
  where batchid = l_batchid and a2 is not null 
  group by a1,a2,to_char(a4,'RRRRMMDD'),to_char(a5,'RRRRMMDD'),vap_code,vat_code
  having sum(nvl(a6,0)+nvl(a7,0)) <> 0
);
```

The `minus` has to have the same data type in each branch, so this is taking the result of your second query and converting the date strings back to dates to make that work. It's possible doing so will still reverse whatever is causing the discrepancy, but the subquery ought to prevent that.

If you don't have dates with times other than midnight, and don't have any negative years, I'm struggling to see what the problem might be. If this does identify the offending row - if it exists - it might become obvious...

(Incidentally, something that won't affect what you're seeing, but don't you want to use `nvl()` inside the `sum()` calls in your select list, not just in the `having` clause?)

Comment: Yes, Alex got the record, it was having a different time . But, I don't get why wasn't this showing before, when I ran the simple query of a4!= trunc(a4).

Comment: Moreover, I would use nvl() inside the sum() calls , but the "mastermind" who has written this code hasn't used.

Comment: Was it a4 or a5 that had the non-midnight time? Maybe you only checked one of the columns before? But the query I put as a comment on Maheswaran's answer or changing your query to use a date mask with time components (comment on question) should have revealed that already. Strange.

Answer (score 3):

If `a4` is a date column, probably you need to nullify the time element. Else for every different time, the count varies. So, we need to instruct the database, to consider the date only.

`TO_CHAR(date,'RRRRMMDD')` or simply `TRUNC(DATE_COLUMN)` will do it.

Comment: The time wont be considered

Comment: If a4 is a date column, probably you need to nullify the time element. can you explain why please?

Comment: The above query is a part of a main code for which time element has already been truncated and the nls_element has been set in a way that the time element has been excluded

Comment: Simply Kalai, `16-JUNE-2016 09:00:00` and `16-JUNE-2016 10:00:00` are different.

Comment: @krishb591993 you mean, your `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` is Date only? I dont see any other issue with your query

Comment: @MaheswaranRavisankar Yes my NLS_DATE_FORMAT is date only, moreover what I meant is that all the records that are entered here are with time element 00:00:00 when I convert the NLS_DATE_FORMAT, so we can consider the time element as not the issue here

Comment: @krishb591993 you run both the query in same session and schema?  Just trying to figure out possibilities.

Comment: @krishb591993 - so if you do `select * from table1 where a4 != trunc(a4) or a5 != trunc(a5)` it returns no rows?

Comment: @MaheswaranRavisankar Yes, I run both these queries in the same session and schema.

Comment: @AlexPoole Yes, it wont return any rows.

Comment: @krishb591993 It wont or it didn't after trying? I suspect it a lot.

Comment: @MaheswaranRavisankar it wont . I am sorry but I am at work and handling multiple issues.

Answer (score 0):

As the difference between the two queries is that in the second one you are truncating the dates in `a4` abd `a5`, the simplest way to list the differences should be:

```
select *
from   table1
where  batchid = l_batchid
and    a2 is not null
and    (a4 > trunc(a4) or a5 > trunc(a5));
```